# flutter plugin: Couldn't read file LocalFile: path to kotlin class

Tags: java, kotlin, flutter

I have developed a flutter plugin with a java plugin class.
Now flutter is somehow searching for a kotlin plugin class which of course does not exist.
The error message is:

> Couldn't read file LocalFile:
>   '...\flutter_camera_permission\android\src\main\kotlin\com\tobiasgubo\camera_permission\CameraPermissionPlugin.kt'
>   even though it exists.

the class that should be called is CameraPermissionPlugin.java

How can I tell flutter that the base class is java not kotlin?
The strange thing is if I build the andoid project directly everything is working.

Comment: Do you get this while debugging or after compiling as a final app? Maybe its looking the wrong place. I know this is not python but files are not found when I try running from within my IDE.

Comment: I get it for both. For a production build and when I run the app for debugging.

Comment: From what I read there seem to be a bug in the dev version and people have solved the issue by actually using a beta version.

Comment: if you provide the version of flutter plugin I can confirm it

Comment: I tested it with the current stable version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 and the current beta channel right now but still getting the error

Comment: the link to the plugin is https://github.com/tobiasgubo/flutter_camera_permission if this helps you

Comment: You do not have the version wich points to wrong direction of files. Is there something else that might misslead the compiler? Is this plugin you make to be open source? I have the right tools to do some testing if you like I have nothing important to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205813/discussion-between-stian-diehard-and-tobias-gubo).